# What does second last employer means?

Tags: software-industry, employer

Say, for example I have worked in the following companies,

```
Company A => 2010 - 2011
Company B => 2011 - 2012 
Company C => 2012 - Till Date
Company D => Have offer
```

Now assume Company D is asking to submit documents from my second last employer. So from the list of companies given, which company would be qualified as second last employer?

Comment: Do you have a preference on documents from which company you would submit? For example, would you prefer it if they wanted documents from company C or company B?

Comment: Hi Raj, in this case, instead of playing guessing games, I'd suggest just asking for clarification from the recruiter/hiring manager. As you can see from the answers, all we can really do is guess, and that's not what we're here for. Check out [help/on-topic] and be sure to take the [about]. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd guess that with common usage, it'd Company B:

- Last employer = Company C.
- Second to last = Company B.

But you could always ask them.

Comment: .... why? It sounds like you are simply guessing at the answer.

Comment: @enderland - Which is the reason the author's question is a bad question.

Answer (score 3):

Since Company D asked the question, why don't you get the clarification from them? Since Company D's question is poorly phrased, there is a chance that whatever answer we give you is the wrong answer, because Company D meant to say something else.

I'll take a guess. I am basing my guess on the guess that Company D wants to have documents from your last two employers - that would be B and C. You probably supplied to them the documents from C, so that's not an issue. Now, they want you to supply the documents from B, so that they can sit fat and happy.

Comment: I think the ambiguity springs from the fact that C could be considered either the 'last' or 'current' employer, making the distinction for second last equally ambiguous.